# MJML Font issue - mj-font not loads font in actual Email Template

Tags: mjml

I am trying to use Google "Inter" Font in my MJML Template.

I have used mj-font, which is simple and should work with google fonts. In MJML Online Editor everything works fine, but in actual Email Template font is not working.

Here is short screenshot of my code

[image]

I added font-family to mj-text tags.

MJML version 4.8.1

Comment: When you say the font doesn't load, how and where are you testing this exactly? Web fonts are not very well supported across email clients, so make sure you test in a client that do support them. (See https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-at-font-face/)

Comment: Thanks, It make sense